# Different Pipe Based on Filter RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following problem. I want to subscribe to an observable using the async pipe in Angular. But the data in the pipe can originate from different data sources and the pipe can look different depending on the data source.

The way it is implemented now does not work, because I override the first value of `this.data$` and thus source A never gets subscribed to.

Is it possible to 'split' the pipe depending on a filter?

**problem.component.ts:**

```
// Data source A and logic A 
this.data$ = this.service.context.pipe(
  filter(context => context.flag === true),
  switchMap(context => this.dataSourceA(context.id))
  map(data => this.processDataA(data))
);

// Data source B and logic B 
this.data$ = this.service.context.pipe(
  filter(context => context.flag === false),
  switchMap(context => this.dataSourceB(context.id))
  map(data => this.processDataB(data))
);
```

**problem.component.html**

```
<pro-table [data]="data$ | async"></pro-table>
```

Comment: What stops you from using an `if else` statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the logic to your `switchMap()`

```js
this.data$ = this.service.context.pipe(
   switchMap(context => context.flag
      ? this.dataSourceA(context.id).pipe(map(d => this.processDataA(d)))
      : this.dataSourceB(context.id).pipe(map(d => this.processDataB(d)))
   )
);
```

Comment: How would you solve this problem if `context.flag` is not a boolean but for example an enum?

Comment: @mafus1, simply `switch` on the `context` ensuring eash branch returns an `Observable`.

Comment: @mafus1 dealing with logic in an observable stream can get very verbose with the source code. I have a few operators that let you express some logic in a declarative way. https://github.com/reactgular/observables

Answer (score 0):

That's just wrong way to achieve the result you desire. You have to take over to something called "higher order observable": `Observable<Observable<T>>`. Like a "higher order function" (that able to produce another function based on it's arguments), this guy is able to produce another `Observable` based on whatever parametrization you rely on.

```
this.service.context.pipe(
  switchMap(context => context.flag ? this.dataSourceA(context.id).pipe(...) : this.dataSourceB(context.id).pipe(...))
);
```

...it might seem a littble bit esoteric at the beginging, but actually it isn't.  \

---

P.S. Important point to remember: *higher order observables* let you parametrize your streams if a fancy way: by dealing with **streams of streams**.

Comment: @Reactgular, then what is it?

Comment: A higher order observable is one that emits another observable, and then is usually followed by a `mergeAll`. There is no higher order here in your example. Your code does answer the question. So I removed my down vote, but the description isn't correct.

Comment: @Reactgular, you are missing that `switchMap` is actuallly `pipe(map(), switchAll())` in essence, where `map` is exact point where `Observable<Observable<T>>` (i.e. "stream of streams") is produced; that's what "higher order observable" is.

Comment: @Reactgular, it isn't "bad" to my opinion; I would say that it requires slightly deeper understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Subject` which will catch many data sources and subscribe to that:

```
    this.data$ = new Subject();
    observer = {
     next(data) { this.data$.next(data) },
     error(msg) { /*handle error*/ }
   };
    // Data source A and logic A 
   this.service.context.pipe(
     filter(context => context.flag === true),
     switchMap(context => this.dataSourceA(context.id))
     map(data => this.processDataA(data))
   ).subscribe(observer);

   this.service.context.pipe(
     filter(context => context.flag === false),
     switchMap(context => this.dataSourceB(context.id))
     map(data => this.processDataB(data))
   ).subscribe(observer);
```

In this situation though it seems like you can use the flag to keep it in one chunk:

```
this.service.context.pipe(
     switchMap(context => context.flag ?
         this.dataSourceA(context.id) : this.dataSourceB(context.id)
    )
     map(data => this.processData(data)) // handle both cases
   ).subscribe(observer);
```